# How to solve these elementary algebra questions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1. Lionel is thinking of two numbers. The sum of twice the larger number and 4 times the smaller number is 40. Twice the smaller number is 4 more than larger number. Find the larger number.
2. Mrs tan spent $140 on buying 4 toys and 6 shirts. If a toy cost twice as much as a shirt, find the cost of a toy.
3. A bakery sells pancakes which come in two flavors,peanut or strawberry. Each peanut pancake cost \$1.10 and each strawberry pancake costs \$1.30. The number of strawberry pancakes sold was twice that of peanut pancakes. The total sale is \$400. Find the **minimum** number of pancakes sold.

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.  Also, many would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Find..."), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: Also, periods are supposed to have spaces after them. To write a dollar sign on this site, you need to precede it with a backslash, like this: `\$` produces $.

Comment: Also, a user has edited your title to better reflect the content of your questions. In general, questions should have titles that tell users at a glance what the topic will be.

Answer (score 1):

1) Let the two number be $x$ and $Y$ with $x<y$. Then we have

> $2y + 4x=40$; $2x=4+y$

So $y=8$ which is the larger number.

2) Let the toy cost be $x$ and shirt cost be $y$. Then we have

> $4x+6y=140$; $x=2y$

So $x=20$, which is the toy cost.